# Create An Array Class With Certain Operation To Implement

Tags: ruby, arrays, class, methods

I am currently working on a basic Ruby programming project, that focuses on creating classes, and operations on those classes. I have very little experience, but understand the general idea of Ruby.

My task is making an Array2 class. Creating arrays from the class, perform operations on the arrays. The methods I attempted are a to-string method, and a is-reverse method that has two array parameters, and tests if the first array is the reverse of the second array.

Here is my attempt, I tried but I am having trouble passing the arrays properly into the class. Also I believe that I am having some calling complications.

```
class Array2
def initialize (a)
    @array = Array.new(a)
end

def to_s
    return @array
end

def isreverse (array1,array2)
    reverasea = Array.new
    reverasea = array1.reverse
    if  (reversea = array2) then
        return "The First Array Is The Reverse Of The Second Array"
    else
        return "The First Array Is Not The Reverse Of The Second Array"
    end
end
end

array1 = ["4","5","6","7"]
array2 = ["7","6","5","3"]

a1 = Array2.new(array1)
a2 = Array2.new(array2)

puts a1.to_s
puts a2.to_s
puts a1.isreverse(array1, array2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an assignment where you probably meant equality test:

```
 if  (reversea = array2) then
```

you could dispense with reversea entirely and just test (this requires a reverse method in `Array2`)

```
if (array1.reverse == @array) then
```

I would personally make isreverse a boolean, and eliminate the need to pass in the same array again:

```
def isreverse? (array1)
    return (@array.reverse == array1)
end
```

then use it like

```
puts "The First Array Is#{a1.isreverse?(a2)?"":" Not"} The Reverse Of The Second Array"
```

put it all together and it looks like:

```
class Array2
    def initialize (a)
        @array = Array.new(a)
    end

    def to_s
        return @array
    end

    def reverse
        @array.reverse
    end

    def isreverse? (array1)
        return (array1.reverse == @array)
    end
end

array1 = ["4","5","6","7"]
array2 = ["7","6","5","3"]

a1 = Array2.new(array1)
a2 = Array2.new(array2)

puts a1.to_s
puts a2.to_s
puts "The First Array Is#{a1.isreverse?(a2)?"":" Not"} The Reverse Of The Second Array"
```

[fiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com/riddles/cf2cf)

Answer (score 1):

Here are some adjustments to your existing approach. I put in comments where I changed the original::

```
class Array2
  def initialize (a)
    @array = Array.new(a)
  end

  def to_array   # to_s is a misnomer: it doesn't return a string
    return @array
  end

  def isreverse (a)
    #reverasea = Array.new  NOTE this is not needed; the following .reverse creates a new array for you
    reversea = a.to_array.reverse  # get the reverse of the array represented

    # NOTE = is assign, == is compare in this case
    # The following compares the reversed of the array `a` with the array value of this class, @array
    if  (reversea == @array) then
      return "The First Array Is The Reverse Of The Second Array"
    else
      return "The First Array Is Not The Reverse Of The Second Array"
    end
  end
end

array1 = ["4","5","6","7"]
array2 = ["7","6","5","3"]

a1 = Array2.new(array1)
a2 = Array2.new(array2)

puts a1.to_array  # (renamed)
puts a2.to_array  # (renamed)
#puts a1.isreverse(array1, array2)  NOTE you don't need to pass array1 into class a1 since it is already made from array1
puts a1.isreverse(a2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would go for something simpler such as:

```
Filename: reverser.rb

class Reverser
  def self.is_reverse_of(array1,array2)
    array1_reversed=array1.reverse
    is_or_isnt= (array1_reversed==array2)? 'Not ' : ''
    return "The First Array Is #{is_or_isnt}The Reverse Of The Second Array"
  end
end
puts Reverser.is_reverse_of(["4","5","6","7"], ["7","6","5","4"])
puts Reverser.is_reverse_of(["4","5","6","7"], ["7","6","5","3"])

ruby reverser.rb
The First Array Is Not The Reverse Of The Second Array
The First Array Is The Reverse Of The Second Array
```

The idea being to use a class level method and not instantiate as much and have less code.

Comment: Alright the code seems a lot more straightforward, and I can see how everything was passed. Thanks alot for you help